# Is there a 3D spin glass that's paramagnetic at all finite temperatures?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model, spin-models

Here, I'm defining spin glass where the couplings $\mathbf{J}$ are sampled from some product measure (say Gaussian or $\pm 1$ random bond). And by paramagnetic, I mean that the overlap distribution averaged over disorder, $\overline{P}(q)$, is Gaussian in the thermodynamic limit ($N \to \infty$), where
$$q = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i}\sigma_i^{\alpha}\sigma_j^{\beta},$$
with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ denoting two independent samples from the Boltzmann distribution.

Trivially, the ferromagnetic $1D$ Ising is paramagnetic for all $T$ (setting $\mathbf{J}=+1$).

The random-bond Ising in $2D$ is also fully paramagnetic within some range of $p$, where $p$ is the probability that $J=+1$ for each bond: http://web.mit.edu/8.334/www/grades/projects/projects17/PeterLu.pdf

How about for $3D$? From simulation, it appears that the $3D$ spin glass with Gaussian coupling displays a ferromagnetic phase transition at finite temperature $T_c > 0$, https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9906076, and most other glass models in $3D$ behave similarly as well. Is there any formal (or informal) reasoning that guarantees a phase transition in $3D$ regardless of the distribution of $\mathbf{J}$?

Perhaps something related to the scaling of free energy cost of forming spin domains would be helpful, but the entropic term ($TS$) seems a bit intractable for a $3D$ domain.